# CMake find_package not working for Eigen?

Tags: cmake, travis-ci, eigen, eigen3

I'm currently developing a Kalman Filtering library using Eigen and I've successfully gotten it working on my development Mac. Now I'm trying to set it up with Travis CI and CMake is having trouble with finding the package. First I `sudo apt install libeigen3-dev` and then attempt to run cmake with the following configuration:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(KFilter VERSION 0.1.0)

find_package (Eigen3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
add_library(KFilter KFilter.cpp)
target_link_libraries(KFilter Eigen3::Eigen)
```

This builds just fine on my Mac, but in Travis CI it errors out with the following:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (add_library):
  Target "KFilter" links to target "Eigen3::Eigen" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing?
```

Why is would I be getting this error at line 5 when the find_package seems to be successful? I'm following [this](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCMakeGuide.html) guide from the Eigen website.

Travis CI is running Ubuntu 16.04 with CMake 3.12 and the Eigen3 debian package, while my Mac is running CMake 3.13 with Eigen installed through homebrew. I'm really confused as to why CMake is behaving differently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't mention which version of Eigen3 is being used in each case.

It looks like between Eigen3 3.2 and 3.3 it changed from using `FindEigen3.cmake` to `Eigen3Config.cmake`.  This changed how to include Eigen3 into a project and in 3.3 it uses `Eigen3::Eigen3`.

But as it turns out on Ubuntu 16.04 the package is `libeigen3-dev (3.3~beta1-2)` and 3.3 beta versions didn't export `Eigen3::Eigen3` instead it contains:

```
add_definitions     ( ${EIGEN3_DEFINITIONS} )
include_directories ( ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
```

So just remove `target_link_libraries(KFilter Eigen3::Eigen)` and it should be fine.

Comment: Yes it is the 3.3 beta version, thanks for clarifying! I’ll try this when I get a chance.

Comment: well, and how to alias old version to new one?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me using Ubuntu 16.04 was to remove the `target_link_libraries(KFilter Eigen3::Eigen)` and change in my source file the following line `#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>`