# Adding Eigen library to c++ project using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen, header-only

Unfortunately, i have some problems adding the headers only [Eigen 3.3.7 Library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) to my Makefile with Cmake on my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS system.
I can compile my code using the library by just copying the library folder in the include directory and using
`include_directories(./include/eigen3)` in the CMakeLists.txt file. However, i would much prefer not having the library path hard-coded but being able set it dynamically in the CMakeLists.txt file to make sharing the project with other people easier. Unfortunately, none of the instructions i found worked for me.

I prepared the following minimum code example:

main.cpp:

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{  
    Eigen::Vector3d test_vec(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);
    std::cout << test_vec << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(Eigen-Cmake-Test VERSION 1.0) # set the project name

find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)

include_directories(${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR})

# add the executable
add_executable("${PROJECT_NAME}" ./main.cpp) 

target_link_libraries("${PROJECT_NAME}" Eigen3::Eigen)
```

I downloaded the headers only [Eigen 3.3.7 Library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) and renamed the folder to eigen3. The folder was then moved to:
`/usr/local/share/eigen3`

when i run `cmake CMakeLists.txt` i get the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" (requested
  version 3.3) with any of the following names:

    Eigen3Config.cmake
    eigen3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen3"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

As i checked the Eigen library folder i realized that `/usr/local/share/eigen3/cmake` only contained a file named Eigen3Config.cmake.in instead of Eigen3Config.cmake which was required. Why is this the case?

I tried renaming the file to Eigen3Config.cmake. Here the error was the following:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "Eigen3" that is compatible
  with requested version "3.3".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    /usr/local/share/eigen3/cmake/Eigen3Config.cmake, version: unknown



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Furthermore, i also tried the solutions explained [stackoverflow: CMake find_package not working for Eigen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53991812/cmake-find-package-not-working-for-eigen) without success.

How can i make this work properly? Also i think i do not quite understand the underlying system yet. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: The file `Eigen3Config.cmake.in` is a template. When you build the project the file `Eigen3Config.cmake.in` will get converted to `Eigen3Config.cmake` which then would be usable.

Comment: To build my project, which uses the Eigen lib, using cmake the error above implies that i already need the ```Eigen3Config.cmake``` file to be present to build the project. If i can only generate the file by building the project that would be a circular dependency, which confuses me a bit. Or what exactly do you mean by building the project?

Comment: In order to get a better understanding about the different ways to manage libraries in C++, and their advantages and disadvantages i found the following post article quite helpful which i wanted to share: [Approaches to C++ Dependency Management](https://hackernoon.com/approaches-to-c-dependency-management-or-why-we-built-buckaroo-26049d4646e7)

Comment: Furthermore, i also found the following detailed explanation of how to add different library types to a project using cmake very helpful: [Tutorial: Easy dependency management for C++ with CMake and Git](https://foonathan.net/2016/07/cmake-dependency-handling/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problems you are running into are caused by downloading the Eigen source code but not actually building the project.  You may think since its a header only library that there is no build step. Well there is; it builds the package config `.pc` and `Eigen3Config.cmake` files.  One of which you are trying to use.

From my previous comment the file `Eigen3Config.cmake.in` is a template and will be used to generate the Eigen3Config.cmake which then would be usable.

Its probably easier to install the libeigen3-dev package, it is packaged with `/usr/lib/cmake/eigen3/Eigen3Config.cmake`.  If you insist on using `Eigen` from source then build and install it

**If you DO want to download and install as source** maybe take a look at the [INSTALL](https://github.com/libigl/eigen/blob/master/INSTALL) file which has a "Method 2" suggesting how to use it in cmake.